# Looking for old version of JBuilder

Tags: java, jbuilder

I'm looking for any of these versions:JBuilder 3-9, JBuilder X, or JBuilder 2005.  The reason for this is because my computer is old (256 MB, 800 Mhz cpu) but I still like to program.  (Yes, I should upgrade my computer but greenbacks don't grow on trees.)

And to prove that I really do program, I have an open source project where you play the trading card game Magic: The Gathering against the computer, http://code.google.com/p/cardforge  The latest version was downloaded 1,862 times.

Thanks for your time,
 mtgrares

Comment: Doesn't this belong on superuser.com? Not a programming matter, more software matter.

Comment: JBuilder X on a 800Mhz CPU with 256Mb of RAM? Good luck :)

Comment: It's a programming tool. I'd say it belongs here among the developers.

Comment: Green backs don't grow on trees, but you could upgrade to 1gb ram for probably $20. It will make a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

I needed an old version of C++ builder a while back, and got it simply by looking on Ebay. This would be my recommendation.

Comment: The free version would do.  Right now I'm using JBuilder 2 from 1997 if you can believe it.

Comment: No idea if this is legit, but I found <a href="http://jetdl.com/search/JBuilder+2005+Foundation.html">this link</a>.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you could get it but I'd ask for what you exactly need from it.

As I remember from the times I used JBuilder, it wasn't actually faster compared to other Java editors. Have you tried a more recent tool like Netbeans or Eclipse in a minimal configuration using a HotSpot JVM(along with -server parameter)? If you are the kind of guy who prefers to write the code and don't necessarily need a true Java IDE, even vim could do it(and that is fast!!!)

Possible alternatives:
http://www.geany.org
http://www.bluej.org/

Answer (score 1):

You would not believe how much the IDE's have improved since then.  Until you try.  You might even find it worth it.

If you can upgrade your memory then you can really get far for a few pennies.  A 800 MHz is probably a Pentium III which can easily run most modern IDE's if you have enough memory and an older version of Windows.

It appears that Borland (or who bought them) have taken old versions off their website, so you have to buy second hand off Ebay or so.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

jbuilder.. was Extremely memory hungry for its time.

I had to lie down on a bed while it sat there chewing hdd (and my) time. It was a nightmare.  I switched to notepad, much more efficient!   I  remembered VB from 10 years before, that had a good fast IDE, MS know how to do them!     Others are catching up though.. or have caught up.

IDEs have improved.. Last time I checked was a few years ago, but still after jbuilder had been thrown in the bin.  Eclipse is better and free, and IntelliJ is popular. I think they probably still are top IDEs.